# Can I enable/disable some stages of aws_codepipeline in Terraform

Tags: terraform, aws-codepipeline

I have a CodePipeline in terraform as follows:

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "main" {
      stage {
          name = "Source"
          ....
      }
      stage {
          name = "Test"
          ....
      }
      stage { 
          name = "Approval"
          ....
      }
      stage {
          name = "Deployment"
          ....
      }
}
```

is it possible to configure whether I need one of the above stages, for example, If variable enable_approval_stage=1, the stage of Approval is created, if enable_approval_stage=0, the stage of Approval is not created? just like how we set count = 0 in resource {}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My idea was to create two different pipelines, one with the approval stage and one without it. And have them like this:

If manual_approve is true (value is 1):

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "pipeline-manualapprove" {
     count    = "${var.manual_approve}"
```

And if manual_approve is false (value is 0):

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "pipeline-automatic" {
     count    = "${1-var.manual_approve}"
```

Comment: ndaniel, you are smart! If I only need to enable/disable one stage, it does work! the only drawback is 1) some duplicate code, 2) only works to enable/disable ONE stage.  But it is a good workaround Thanks.

Comment: I want to do the same thing and considered creating two separate pipelines but this is a massive duplication of code I really dont want to get into... Is there no other way of making stages conditional? Also I need to decide whether to create or not a number of different stages.

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar problem. I have a "mirroring" stage, which synchronizes a CodeCommit repository to a corporate Gitlab server. I enabled it only for *dev* environment, on the event of merging to **develop** branch. Using the **dynamic** clause, you can achieve your goal. It is being around at least since version 1.1.

Consider a variable:

```
variable "stages" {
  type = set(string)
  default = ["dev","qa","prod"]
}
```

The script would look like this:

```
resource "aws_codepipeline" "pipeline_template" {
  for_each = var.stages

  name = "Awesome pipeline for ${each.key}"
  role_arn = data.aws_iam_role.my_codepipeline_role.arn

  stage {
    name = "Source"
    ....
  }
  stage {
    name = "Test"
    ....
  }

  dynamic "stage" {
    for_each = each.key == "dev" ? [each.key] : []

    content {
      name = "Mirror"
      ....
    }
  }
}
```